# How do I add a new activity from menuItem with Ribbonmenu on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest, menuitem

So I am using the RibbonMenu library fro Android. I want to a start a new activity after a menuItem is selected. This is my menu/main.xml file

`

```
<item android:id="@+id/tactics" android:title="Tactics" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/item2" android:title="Players" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/item3" android:title="Teams" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/item4" android:title="In-Game" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"></item>
```

`

This is how I try to start an activity from my main activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home){
        rbmView.toggleMenu();
    }

    if (id == R.id.tactics){

     // I added a Toast here to print something random. But looks like this is never even getting recognized.
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TouchlineInstructionActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(i);
    }

    return true; 

}
```

And this is my new activity.

`public class TouchlineInstructionActivity extends Activity implements iRibbonMenuCallback{

```
private RibbonMenuView rbmView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_touchline_instruction);

    rbmView = (RibbonMenuView) findViewById(R.id.ribbonMenuView1);
    rbmView.setMenuClickCallback(this);
    rbmView.setMenuItems(R.menu.activity_main);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);}`
```

I have the activity added to my androidmanifest file as follows

`

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TouchlineInstructionActivity" >
    </activity>
</application>`
```

There are no errors or anything. The app launches and works fine. But on clicking the button, the new activity just doesn't start. Any ideas about what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out what I was doing wrong. It's a really stupid mistake honestly. So here goes, this piece of code right here

```
    if (id == R.id.tactics){

 // I added a Toast here to print something random. But looks like this is never even getting recognized.
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TouchlineInstructionActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(i);
}
```

must go in the **public void RibbonMenuItemClick(int itemId)** method not the **onOptionsItemSelected(Item item)** method. It was a really stupid mistake on my part. I don't even know how I thought my code made sense before.